# variable getting emptied or reassinged in JS in an ANGULAR 14 app

Tags: javascript, object, angular14

I am using ng-14, in one of my components I have a variable which I have initialized as an empty object and inside a function am populating it with key-value pairs, though the object is populated with key-value pairs during the next function call, the object is shown empty even though debugging has shown it populated , the variable is not used any where else in order to clarify that it's not reassigned anywhere , what could be the potential reasons , how to rectify

used local storage to store the object its working i mean the object is holding the values , buts it's not a useful approach as I want to clear it on page refresh etc

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, which you are currently using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.